# How do you post json data to HTTPS endpoint from ESP8266MOD?

Tags: esp8266, web-service

Board: ESP8266MOD module from AI Thinker.

Using ArduinoHttpClient I am unable to send a post message to an Azure IOT Hub endpoint. The endpoint is listening on 443 and expects a shared key passed via a custom header.

The error I get is "Connection Timed Out"

Here is the brief sketch

```
char serverAddress[] = "myapp.azure-devices.net";
int port = 443;
string sig = "Azure shared access signature";
HttpClient client = HttpClient(wifiClient, serverAddress, port);
  String jsonPayload = payload; // passed into this function
  client.beginRequest();
  String contentType = "application/json";
  client.post("/devices/deviceId/messages/events?api-version=2016-02-03");
  client.sendHeader(HTTP_HEADER_CONTENT_TYPE, contentType);
  client.sendHeader("Authorization", sig);
  client.sendHeader(HTTP_HEADER_CONTENT_LENGTH, jsonPayload.length());
  client.beginBody();
  client.print(jsonPayload);
  client.endRequest();

  statusCode = client.responseStatusCode();
  response = client.responseBody();
```

The Status Code is -3 indicating a Timeout

I then created a simple REST API that accepts the JSON. Hosted it as an Azure website on port 80.

The board is able to connect to this HTTP endpoint

Question(s):
1. Is the board underpowered to handle HTTPS?
2. Is creating an HTTP proxy the only option?
3. Am I not using the right library?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You are only making an HTTP request to an HTTPS server. It's not going to work.

AFAIK there is no direct support for HTTPS in the ESP8266 libraries, but there is support for SSL, and you can then manually create an HTTP request over that - as detailed in the [HTTPSRequest.ino](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/libraries/ESP8266WiFi/examples/HTTPSRequest/HTTPSRequest.ino) example.

Comment: Thanks for responding. When you say "You are only making an HTTP request to an HTTPS Server", do you mean the library constructs the URL as http:// even though the port specified is 443? 

If I change char serverAddress[] = "myapp.azure-devices.net"; to 
char serverAddress[] = "https://myapp.azure-devices.net"; 

it does not work either.

Comment: Yes, I mean that the library doesn't know that 443 corresponds to HTTPS, since you can run HTTP on any port, not just 80. Also it doesn't know what HTTPS is. It only talks HTTP.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Majenko I was able to find the right solution.

The resolution is [here](https://github.com/arduino-libraries/ArduinoHttpClient/issues/13)

Essentially, a secure WiFiClient needs to be created and used in the HttpClient constructor

1. Paste the HTTPS URL You are trying to connect to, in a browser
   window and grab the SHA1 Fingerprint of the certificate
2. Create aninstance of WifiClientSecure
3. Call Connect on WifiClientSecure passing in the HTTPS URL and Port number
4. Upon successful connection, call the Verify method of WifiClientSecure to verify the fingerprint.
5. Pass the fingerprint from setp1 and URL to this method
6. Use the WifiClientSecure instance when creating an instance of
   HttpClient.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Your link doesn't contain any resolution.

Comment: @m12lrpv check out sandeepmistry's comment in the thread. I added the steps in an attempt to clarify the comments.